# button to act as checkbox and change styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

On my assignment I am only allowed to use a button, so no checkbox. Onclick of the button, certain info in shown. The code I have is working, but my question is how can I get the class to display: none, when the button is clicked again? Kind of like a toggle?

```
const displayScores = (e) => {
    if (
      (e.target.parentNode.querySelector(
        ".display-score-container"
      ).style.display = "none")
    ) {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector(
        ".display-score-container"
      ).style.display = "block";
      e.target.innerHTML = "-";
    } else {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector(
        ".display-score-container"
      ).style.display = "none";
      e.target.innerHTML = "+";
    }
  };






return (
<div className="student-container">
              <img className="student-img" src={students.pic} />
              <div className="student-column">
                <p className="student-item">
                  {" "}
                  {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
                </p>
                <p className="student-item">Email: {students.email}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Company: {students.company}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Skill: {students.skill}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Average: {average}%</p>

                <div className="display-score-container">
                  <p className="student-score">
                    Test 1:{" "}
                    <p className="student-percentage">{students.grades[0]}%</p>
                  </p>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <button
                
                onClick={displayScores}
                className="expand-btn"
              >
                +
              </button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'active' class or some class for that and write css for that particular Class Name. On click add that class to the button and toggle the values.
and put the condition on the class you have added if (active){..} else{..}.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the `displayScore` using the `React.useState` and update the template based on the state.

```
const [displayScore, setDisplayScore] = React.useState(true);

const handleDisplayScores = (e) => {
    setDisplayScore(!displayScore);
  };
          

return (
   <div className="student-container">
              <img className="student-img" src={students.pic} />
              <div className="student-column">
                <p className="student-item">
                  {" "}
                  {students.firstName} {students.lastName}
                </p>
                <p className="student-item">Email: {students.email}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Company: {students.company}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Skill: {students.skill}</p>
                <p className="student-item">Average: {average}%</p>

                {displayScore && (<div  className="display-score-container">
                  <p className="student-score">
                    Test 1:{" "}
                    <p className="student-percentage">{students.grades[0]}% 
                     </p>
                  </p>
                </div>)}

              </div>

              <button  
                onClick={handleDisplayScores}
                className="expand-btn">
                {displayScore ? '-' : '+'}  // set based on your use case.
              </button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do that.
It is working.

```
const displayScores = e => {
            if (e.target.innerHTML === '+') {
                document.querySelector('.display-score-container').style.display =
                    'none';
                e.target.innerHTML = '-';
            } else {
                document.querySelector('.display-score-container').style.display =
                    'block';
                e.target.innerHTML = '+';
            }
        };
```

Of course this is not the only solution. It depends on your hole project.
Hope that I helped you. Have a nice day :)